# Using Django-models, how to form a website which allows creation of additional attributes?

Tags: django

I am developing a simple map repository , and for each map a table has to be created according to the no. of attributes in the map . I also want to give access to the user to create as many additional attributes as he wants to per map . This would mean that each map should have its own model , and if there are additional attributes then changes to the model have to be done on the fly to reflect in the database . How to do this ? I am using a single model as of now .

Comment: I suggest you read *at least* an introduction to database design and relational-database normalization.  Hint: database design is very different from object-oriented design.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an awful idea. Consider creating a second model that has a FK to the map model and implements [EAV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity-attribute-value_model).